# Properly use of BeanListHandler when join tables

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-commons-dbutils

I'm using [DBUtils](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/) in my simple project. I have `Item` and `Person` entity class (`persons` and `items` as tables in database). This simplified the class to better show what I mean. Now i need to get list of items with login names using [BeanListHandler](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbutils/handlers/BeanListHandler.html). To do this i added `login` property to `Item`, but this is ugly solution. Is something better to do that and use advantages of [BeanListHandler](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbutils/handlers/BeanListHandler.html)?

```
public class Person {
   private Long id;
   private String login;
}

public class Item {
   private Long id;
   private String name;
   // ... a lot more properties of item

   private Long personId;  // this is real column in "items" table
   private String login;   // UGLY (login is not in "items" table, only for BeanListHandler)
}

QueryRunner q = new QueryRunner(getDataSource());
String sql = "select i.*, p.login from items i, persons p where p.id = i.personId";
List<Item> l = (List<Item>) q.query(sql, new BeanListHandler<Item>(Item.class));
```